# How to cache/store application settings in a class library

Tags: .net, caching, class-library

i have created a Class Library which may be used from a Windows or Web application.
Some settings which are required by the class library intensively should be read from the app.config or web.config of those calling apps in most of methods inside the class library.
To increase the performance, i want to cache some how these settings info for each app.

how can we do that? one suggestion is using HttpRuntime.Cache object. Another method may be using some static variable to store data but it may have AppDomain / Scope conflict issues..

So, i'm not sure what is the best way for doing this (Note that it is a general class which may be used from Windows or Web apps)

Comment: note that i should do some process on the config settings to get what i actually need to use and this can be time consuming! for example create a DbFactory based on database provider name or similar issues..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is a performance issue in calling App.config members or is it just a guess ? 
Config Accessors do not actually perform I/O from your config classes if coded properly as they generate compiled properties, so I think this not much of a problem and I doubt you would gain performance from caching it.

Comment: you are right to some extent about config access, but i should do some process on the config settings to get what i actually need to use and this can be time consuming! for example create a DbFactory based on database provider name or similar issues..

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of internal conflict about whether I should store class library settings in the caller's .config or if I should just pass that configuration information to the class library at the time of instantiation.  One solution would be to alter your class library so it takes its configuration information at creation time (the calling app can still generate this from its .config).  That way you can have the calling app control the caching of the configuration data.

For example - the web app reads its web.config for each request and passes it as a configuration object, whereas the windows app reads its app.config into a configuration object once and stores it somewhere so it can continuously reinstantiate the library without needing to re-read its app.config.